# Visual Studio's Graphic Diagnostics not capturing any data

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, directx, callstack

I'm trying to capture a DirectX 9 game's frame to see information about how it is rendered. This part can be achieved with PIX, which works correctly. PIX, however, does not capture any call stack for D3D events, whereas Visual Studio does.

So I tried to use Visual Studio's Graphics Diagnostics instead. I don't have the code for the game, but AFAIK this can be done for external programs too. In the Project Properties, I've set the Debugging Command to the application path.

When I do the Graphics Diagnostics, Visual Studio tells me the game doesn't have any debugging information. The game opens up correctly, although without any new HUD, like I think it's meant to. No FPS data is recorded in the graphs, however, and when I press "Capture Frame" nothing gets captured.

Am I doing something wrong, or there's no way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics does not support legacy Direct3D 9.

Keep in mind that legacy Direct3D 9 is over a decade old, and debugging support (i.e. the Debug Runtime) for Direct3D 9 is not available for Windows 8.x or Windows 10.

The *PIX for Windows* tool in the deprecated DirectX SDK works for Direct3D 9, but fails for Direct3D 10 or Direct3D 11 applications on the DirectX 11.1 Runtime or later (i.e. Windows 10, Windows 8.x, Windows 7 SP1+KB2670838).

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/14/directx-11-1-and-windows-7.aspx)